# A customized swap fails in bubbleSort

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

I wrote such a swap function for bubbleSort:

```
function swap(a, b) {
    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

then encapsulate it in the bubbleSort:

```
function bubbleSort(arr) {
    let len = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
            // swap the elements
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]); // use swap here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And test it with:

```
arr = [34, 87, 21, 0, -11];
bubbleSort(arr)
```

but it stay unchanged, what's the problem?

Comment: in javascript, numbers aren't pointers, ur only changing the in function parameters and nothing else.. yes the values `a` and `b` would switch but only INSIDE that function, nothing else that u wanted would've switched

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swap function takes a copy of the number instead of the pointer.. welcome to javascript?

Either way, you would need the array and the indexes to do a swap because objects are pointers, numbers are not

Here's an example

```js
//working swap function
function swap(arr, a, b){
  var tmp=arr[a]
  arr[a]=b
  arr[b]=tmp
}

function bubbleSort(arr) {
    let len = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
            // swap the elements
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                swap(arr, j, j+1); // use swap here.
            }
        }
    }
    return arr //because why not
}

arr = [34, 87, 21, 0, -11];
console.log(bubbleSort(arr))
```

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents...

```
function bubbleSort(arr)  // original algorythm
  {
  for ( let i=arr.length ; --i > 0 ;          )
  for ( let j=0, k=1     ; j < i   ; j++, k++ )  
  if (arr[j] > arr[k])
    [arr[j],arr[k]] = [arr[k],arr[j]]; 
  }
```

```js
const myArr = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];

bubbleSort(myArr)

document.write( JSON.stringify(myArr) )


function bubbleSort(arr)  // optimised algorythm
  {
  for (let i=arr.length, noSwap; --i>0;) // go reverse, important!
    {
    noSwap = true
    for (let j=0, k=1; j<i; j++,k++)  
    if (arr[j] > arr[k])
      {
      [arr[j],arr[k]] = [arr[k],arr[j]]; 
      noSwap = false
      }
    if (noSwap) break
  } }
```

For those who wonder why in the BubbleSort algorithm the first index must necessarily start from the right to go up to the left
while the following clues go in the other direction, I made this animation to visualize its logic.

the idea of Bubble Sort is to push the highest value to the right, much like air bubbles in a liquid.

this code also makes it possible to realize why the performance of this type of sorting is poor, unless, by chance, the elements are close to the correct order (which is still hazardous).

```js
const
    btSort    = document.querySelector('#bt-sort')
  , btGener   = document.querySelector('#bt-gen')
  , movinBars = document.querySelector('#moving-bars')
  , arrLen    = document.querySelector('#arr-len')
  , delay     = ms => new Promise( r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  ;
// input range HTML system to get future length of the arr to sort
arrLen.value   = arrLen.closest('label').dataset.val;
arrLen.oninput =_=>{ arrLen.closest('label').dataset.val = arrLen.value }

const 
  arrBars = (()=>  // => { set size, setBarLeft(), setBarClass() }
    {
    let
      len  = 0
    , Keys = []  // array keys on Bars
    , Bars = []  // Bars elements
      ;
    const
      shuffleKeys =_=>
        {
        let X = len, Y;
        while (X)
          {
          Y = (Math.random() * X--) | 0;
          [Keys[X], Keys[Y]] = [ Keys[Y], Keys[X]];
          }
        }
    , genBars =_=>
        {
        let xHeight= 0, szMin = (240/len)|0, szMax = (53.7143 -(len*(4/7)))|0;

        let hg = [];
        Bars = new Array(len);

        for (let i=0;i<len;i++)
          {
          xHeight += szMin + ((Math.random() *szMax)|0);
          hg.push( xHeight )
          }   
        for (let i=0;i<len;i++)
          {
          Bars[i]              = document.createElement('div')
          Bars[i].style.height = `${hg[Keys[i]]}px`
          Bars[i].style.left   = `${i *17}px`
          movinBars.appendChild(Bars[i])
          }
        }
    , Obj = 
        { set size( length ) 
            {
            if ( len !== length )        { Keys = [...Array(length).keys()]           };
            for( let i=0;i<len;i++)      { delete Bars[i];                            };
            while (movinBars.firstChild) { movinBars.removeChild(movinBars.lastChild) };
            len = length;

            shuffleKeys();
            genBars();
            }
        , bubbleSort: function* ()  // optimuzed version
          {
          let noSwap;
          for (let i=len; --i>0 ;)
            {
            noSwap = true;
            for (let j=0, k=1, j$=Keys[j], k$=Keys[k]; j<i; j$=Keys[++j], k$=Keys[++k] )
              {
              if ( j$>k$ )
                {
                Keys[j] = k$;
                Keys[k] = j$;
                noSwap = false;
                yield ([ j, k, true ]);
                }
              else
                yield ([ j, k, false ]);
              }
              if (noSwap) break;
            }
          }
        , setBarLeft: (indx, vLeft ) => new Promise( r =>
          {
          let bar = Bars[indx];
          bar.ontransitionend =_=>
            {
            bar.ontransitionend = null
            r()
            }
          bar.style.left = `${vLeft *17}px`
          })
        , setBarsClass( x, y, onOff, doSwapp ) 
          {
          Bars[x].classList.toggle('Mov1',onOff)
          Bars[y].classList.toggle('Mov2',onOff)

          if (!onOff && doSwapp)
            {
            Bars[x].classList.remove('Mov1')
            Bars[y].classList.remove('Mov2')

            let hg_x = Bars[x].style.height
              , lf_x = Bars[x].style.left
              ;
            Bars[x].style.height = Bars[y].style.height
            Bars[x].style.left   = Bars[y].style.left

            Bars[y].style.height = hg_x
            Bars[y].style.left   = lf_x
            }
          }
        }
      ;
    return Obj;
    })();


/***************************** main part ***********/
btSort.disabled = true;

btGener.onclick =_=>
  {
  btGener.disabled = true;
  arrLen.disabled  = true;
  arrBars.size     = arrLen.valueAsNumber;
  btSort.disabled  = false;
  }
btSort.onclick = async () =>
  {
  btSort.disabled = true;
  for await (let [ x,y, doSwapp ] of arrBars.bubbleSort())
    {
    arrBars.setBarsClass( x, y, true, doSwapp )

    if (doSwapp)
      {
      await arrBars.setBarLeft( x, y )
      await arrBars.setBarLeft( y, x )  
      }
    else
      await delay(80);

    arrBars.setBarsClass( x, y, false, doSwapp )

    await delay(90) 
    }
  btGener.disabled = false;
  arrLen.disabled  = false;
  }
```

```css
body {
  background  : #14141f;
  margin      : 0;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 18px;
  }
header {
  background : #2d2d47;
  padding    : 1.3rem 0;
  }
button {
  border           : 3px solid #29293a;
  border-radius    : .8rem;
  background-color : #5b5b8d;
  color            : black;
  font-size        : 1.2rem;
  width            : 7.6rem;
  vertical-align   : middle;
  margin           : 0 0 0 1.5rem;
  }
button:not(:disabled):hover {
  background-color : #67678a;
  color            : whitesmoke;
  cursor           : pointer;
  }
button:disabled {
  background-color : #5b5b8d;
  border-color     : darkslategrey;
  color            : #29293a;
  }
#moving-bars {
  position : relative;
  margin   : 20px 0 0 20px;
  }
#moving-bars > div {
  position   : absolute;
  background : #3e3e50;
  width      : 10px;
  top        : 0;
  }
#moving-bars > div.Mov1 {
  transition : left .3s ease-in-out;
  background : crimson;
  }
#moving-bars > div.Mov2 {
  transition : left .3s ease-in-out;
  background : #ffff0088;
  }
/******************************/
label.rg  {
  display : inline-block;
  height  : 1.8rem;
  padding : .3rem .5rem 0 1rem;
  color   : black;
  }
label.rg input {
  vertical-align : middle;
  width          : 18rem;
  }
label.rg::before {
  display     : inline-block;
  content     : attr(data-lib);
  font-weight : bold;
  color          : #5f5fc2;
  }
label.rg::after {
  content        : attr(data-val);
  display        : inline-block;
  font-size      : 1.2rem;
  vertical-align : middle;
  border         : 1px solid #5b5b8d;
  width          : 2.8rem;
  text-align     : center;
  border-radius  : .6rem;
  padding        : .2rem 0;
  margin-left    : .2rem;
  color          : #5f5fc2;
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <button id="bt-sort" >  Sort    </button>
    <button id="bt-gen"  > Generate </button>
    <label class="rg" data-val="12" data-lib="Len: "> <input type="range" id="arr-len" min="9" max="40" step="1" ></label>
  </header>
  <div id="moving-bars"></div>
```